# Summing values in field using QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, summarizing, qgis-1

Using QGIS 1.8, I've got a shapefile with an integer field called `"AREA"` and I'd like to sum the values which are in this shapefile.

Does anybody know how to?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 29):

You can immediately get field summary data, including sums, from the menu Vector|Analysis tools|Basic statistics:

[image]

You could also open the .dbf file associated with your shapefile in Excel or OpenOffice, and you'll be able to work with all the field values as a spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank's a lot, Simbamangu. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Robert300 accept the answer with the checkbox

Answer (score 2):

Using the DB Manager SQL window, you can use SQL expressions with SQL spatial functions to sum, group, etc.

This can be used on shapefiles, or any other type of layer in your QGIS project:

[image]