# Lengths through Attribute Vectors

Tags: qgis, vector, attribute-table

I have a line that goes through sections of land in which has attribute data assigned to it.  I want to compute out how long of pipe goes through each different type of land.
As you can see, the cyan lines are the boundaries of land and this one happens to have the attribute "Cultivated_Crops".

The best way I know of doing this is through autocad just measuring the distance by hand.  I'm not sure of any quick solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Intersect](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18453/how-to-create-a-new-layer-from-overlap-between-two-layers) your parcels and pipeline then [add length field and calculate](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/calculating_line_lengths.html). That is assuming your parcels are polygons. This will add the parcel attributes to the lines, clipping them at intersections.

From here it would be a good idea to [summarize the attributes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37712/sum-values-in-a-field) for length on each unique parcel ID; in some cases a line might zigzag in and out of a parcel or due to the parcels' shape intersect twice, summarizing will give the total length within each parcel.

Before you do this though make sure your data (all of it) is in a suitable projected coordinate system or your lengths would be nonsensical.

Comment: Now i have section of pipe that went outside the polygons boundary.  Is there a way to have this output as null?  For further explanation, The pipe extends past the polygons at some points and I want to include those as another length but just have them be counted as "Null".  I know I will need to use another geometric function but I tried others with no avail.

Comment: I have used the Symmetrical Difference command and that gives me what I want but I just need to add it to the table of the intersection.  If there is a different way to do this more efficiently then let me know.  Thank you.