# Sum of values grouped by owner

Tags: qgis, expression, sorting, summarizing

When I try to use the following expression, the preview shows me the correct sum, but when I click ok I get this notification. This tells me it can't calculate column "Subsidie J"

It seems that it can't find the value for column "Subsidie J" but it's all in the attribute table.

Am I using the wrong expression? The value of "Subsidie J" is a CASE IF .... THEN ... END expression. Now I want the sum of these values sorted by owner.

[image]

Comment: The function if well written. Could you please share your data ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Summing data from a column in attribute table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/summing-data-from-a-column-in-attribute-table). You just need to add the owner as a grouping factor/filter.

Comment: I just tried   round(sum("Subsidie J", "Eigenaar"),0)  and again the preview is showing correct. But when I click ok I get the same error message.

Comment: In your above expression, there is something missing, it should be `round(sum("Subsidie J", group_by:="Eigenaar"),0)`

Comment: I would bet on the data, as @CésarArquero already mentioned

Comment: I also tried to use the expression behind "Subsidie J" in the new one. This is the example. The case when then is the expression behand "Subsidie J". Again it returns a perfect preview but an error when clicking Ok.

Comment: I think it must be something wrong in the data structure or data type. Share with us just a little piece of that shp please.

Comment: @Taras, What do you mean by 'I would bet on the data'?

Comment: @CésarArquero Ok I will share a little piece, but how do I do that?

Comment: Means that your attribute `"Subsidie J"` can hold some `NULL` values or something else which makes you impossible to execute the formula because of the data specifications etc.

Comment: Just zip that shp and put it on WeTransfer or any cloud

Comment: @CésarArquero here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5zkpwq7d9t5jmus/example.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Bram Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: @Joseph QGIS 2.18.28

Comment: I have tried exactly what you did and It worked. May me because you share a portion of the shp without errors?

Comment: @CésarArquero You are correct. it works with me too (in the portion of the shp). How can I find the attributes which gives the error? (In the big shp). Do you have any idea? Thanks for trying!

Comment: Could you share your complete shp to find out the error ?

Comment: @CésarArquero I found it! You mentioned earlyer that it is probably cause of the data. So I checked the data again. There were some Null values so I changed the CASE.. IF.. THEN expression of the "Subsidie J" Column. I implemented at the end of the expression ELSE 0 and it worked fine. Now the SUM expression works fine. Thanks for helping me out of this one!! You made me look somewhere else and it worked. Great! thx

Comment: That is great. I recommend you to edit or answer your own question to avoid been classified as unanswered. Regards !