# Categorizing most often attributes in column

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have a shp point layer with a `"USER_ID"` column. There is about 19 thousands features. Some of `"ID"`'s enters the list only ones or twice, but some of them enters 50 or more than 100 times.

I need to find the users which most often meet in this column. By all means it is possible to categorize this layer, but I think that the result shouldn't be clear. Is there a way to categorize only 50 most frequent values of a column?

[image: data example]

Comment: Have you seen this topic [Summing data from a column in attribute table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/301852/99589)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not the best solution according to the data amount, i.e. 19 thousands features. But perhaps you are working with a database.

In terms of QGIS I can suggest using a *Virtual Layer* through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

With the following query, it is possible to achieve the result, i.e. to find the users which most often meet in this column. Only users that are met more than 50.

```sql
SELECT p."USER_ID", COUNT() AS "count"
FROM "points_layer" AS p
GROUP BY p."USER_ID"
HAVING COUNT() > 50
```

Or if you want to categorize only 50 most frequent values of a column that use this query

```sql
SELECT p."USER_ID", COUNT() AS "count"
FROM "points_layer" AS p
GROUP BY p."USER_ID"
ORDER BY COUNT() DESC
LIMIT 50
```

*Note:* The result will not maintain the geometry of the original point layer.

If you wish to maintain geometry of your point layer it is important to understand whether your users with same id share the same location. Nevertheless, when the geometry has to be kept, please extend the query with `p.geometry`

```sql
SELECT p."USER_ID", COUNT() AS "count", p.geometry
FROM "points_layer" AS p
GROUP BY p."USER_ID"
HAVING COUNT() > 50
```

Comment: Thank you, @Taras! I got virtual layer with count for each user. The easiest way to proceed and get geometry is to join that two layers and to categorize by "COUNT" column? Am I right?

Comment: Please check the updates)