# Determining how many of my coordinates overlap with layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon

I am working on a project about a certain animal species. I have gotten coordinates from where the species has been observed.

Now I want to know what percentage of the observations are from gardens/residential area and what percentage from forest/ edges of forests.

I have found a layer for living areas so the animals found there would count as 'found in garden/residential area'.

So my question is how do I find out how many of my coordinates overlap with this layer and how many do not?

Comment: @Taras I wasn't sure how to describe my question that is why I couldn't find a matching thread. Thank you for your answer. I tried to join attributes by location. What do you mean by 'add a field with '1/0'? can you do this while joining the layers or afterwards?

Comment: @Taras Yes I understand what you mean. Only I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Let me know if something is still not clear in my answer

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that there is a CSV-file (in UTF-8) *'animals.csv'*, see image below

[image: input_csv]

**Step 1.** In QGIS create a new QGIS Project. Then proceed with `Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer ...`.

[image: step_1]

**Step 2.** Add your area via `Layer > Add Layer > Add Vector Layer ...`. After adding areas your QGIS working window may look as follows.

[image: step_2]

**Step 3.** Apply the ["Join attributes by location"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location) as demonstrated in the image below.

[image: step_3]

**Step 4.** In the attribute table of the result from a previous step apply ["Field calculator"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) with a small expression for

```sql
CASE
   WHEN "Name" IS NULL THEN 0
   ELSE 1
END
```

Alternative is: `if("Description", 1, 0)`

[image: step_4]

So, the updated Attribute table will now look as demonstrated in the image below

[image: new_at]

**Step 5.** In this last stage I will offer not the best solution in terms of performance for large data but I reckon it is simple to understand. Attaining basic statistics by means of a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` with this query:

```sql
WITH o AS (
    SELECT COUNT() AS "overlap"
    FROM "Joined layer"
    WHERE "calc" = 1
),

no AS (
    SELECT COUNT() AS "not_overlap"
    FROM "Joined layer"
    WHERE "calc" = 0
)

SELECT
    "o"."overlap",
    "no"."not_overlap"
FROM
    "o", "no"
```

And your output is:

[image: output]

*Note*: that the output does not include geometry.

Additionally, I am providing you with some references that are necessary to read.

---

**References:**

- [QGIS Tutorials and Tips | Importing Spreadsheets or CSV files](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html)
- [Summing data from a column in attribute table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/summing-data-from-a-column-in-attribute-table/301852#301852)
- [Getting tabular statistics from table using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43037/getting-tabular-statistics-from-table-using-qgis)

Answer (score 0):

A PyQGIS solution.

Let's assume there is a project folder with two files: *'test_points.csv'* and *'test_polygons.shp'*, see image below.

[image: input]

In QGIS they will look like:

[image: qgis]

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and copy&edit&paste the script below:

```py
# defining inputs
project_path = 'C:/Users/DUBRTARA/Desktop/test/project/'
csv_file_name = 'test_points.csv'
shp_file_name = 'test_polygons.shp'

# Step 1: reading a CSV file with points and converting it into a shapefile
uri_csv_file = 'file:///' + project_path + csv_file_name + "?encoding={0}&delimiter={1}&xField={2}&yField={3}&crs={4}".format("UTF-8",",","x","y","epsg:31469")
# In .format("UTF-8",",","x","y","epsg:31469")
# "UTF-8" stands for encoding : data encoding (optional)
# "," : is a delimiter inm the input file
# xField : is a column name for longitude value
# yField : is a column name for latitude value
# crs : is a Coordinate system in EPSG number
points = QgsVectorLayer(uri_csv_file, csv_file_name.split(".")[0], "delimitedtext")
if not points.isValid():
    print ("{} layer was not loaded".format(csv_file_name))

# Step 2: reading a shapefile with polygons
path_to_shp_file_name = project_path + shp_file_name
polygons = QgsVectorLayer(path_to_shp_file_name, shp_file_name.split(".")[0], "ogr")
if not polygons.isValid():
    print ("{} layer was not loaded".format(shp_file_name))

# Step 3: selecting point features that intersect polygon features
points_in = processing.run("qgis:selectbylocation",{
                                'INPUT' : points,
                                'PREDICATE' : 0, #corresponds to 'intersects'
                                'INTERSECT' : polygons,
                                'METHOD' : 0
                                })['OUTPUT']

# creating a dictionary for output
result = {}
# nesting results into the dictionary
result['points in polygons'] = points_in.selectedFeatureCount()
result['points not in polygons'] = points.featureCount() - points_in.selectedFeatureCount()

# printing the result
print(result)

# for more details run the following command >>> processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:selectbylocation")
```

Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output that will look like `{'points in polygons': 4, 'points not in polygons': 1}`, see image below

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- [Geodose | Python QGIS Tutorial: Adding CSV Data](https://www.geodose.com/2018/07/python-qgis-tutorial-adding-csv-data.html)
- [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook » 3. Loading Layers](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#loading-layers)
- [QGIS Docs » 23.1.17.10. Select by location](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-location)
- [PyQGIS 101: Running Processing tools](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-running-processing-tools/)